# Error Output SQL Script, Invalid default value for 'date'

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, apache2

Background:

Apache2: 2.4.18
PHP: 7.0.1X
Software: PHPMelody

Issue:

I am getting an error output on the sql execution of:

ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 150: Invalid default value for 'date'

Code at line 150:

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pm_ads_log`;
CREATE TABLE `pm_ads_log` (
  `log_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `ad_id` mediumint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ad_type` smallint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `impressions` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `clicks` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `skips` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `date` (`date`,`ad_id`,`ad_type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Im not a php developer or sql db, but right now Im having to deal with both very briefly.

Can anyone provide any guidance to help me get past this?

Answer (score 2):

You've already specified that it should not be null so it won't be blank.

Try removing `DEFAULT '0000-00-00'` as it is the default format anyway.

Comment: I tried removing '0000-00-00'
I tried changing it to '0' and '00-00-0000'

Each instance gave me a similar error, or stated: invalid value for date

Comment: @Fallenour Try removing the word `DEFAULT` too